# ANDROID user created text box?

Tags: android, text, mobile, textbox

I am looking to create an application that allows the user of the app the ability to create their own text box. It would be on top of an image file that I currently load. Basically they would zoom in to a place on the image, then drag with their fingers the position of the needed text box, then the box would be able to accept text...

I cannot find anywhere how I would accomplish this task ??? any suggestions or help would be much appreciated!!!

thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming based on

> "then the box would be able to accept text..."

that you mean the user will be able to type things in to it.

If that is correct then an EditText is what you are looking for. By default this View is not set up to let the user

> "drag with their fingers the position of the needed text box"

In  order to make that work you'd have to write your own OnTouchListener for this view that recognizes the finger motions and changes the size of the EditText accordingly.

Comment: I believe I am on the same page with you... I may be missing something in your answer ( not realizing) but the text box would not exist at all at the beginning of the application. The user would first choose an image file from their sd card, open it and be able to zoom in and out on the image, then create text boxes. This might be a caption for a picture for example. so would creating this OnTouchListner be able to actually create a text box? If so any example or place I could see this done? Once the box is created yes the user would need to be able to fill the box with their text